# Multiplication of two tables in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to create a prolog function that gets a two table multiplication .

My code is currently as follows:

mult(L1,L2,L).
So for example I would like a query such as:

?- mult([x,x],[x,x,x],R).
To display something like:

R=[x,x,x,x,x,x]
how could I fix my code?

i tried with recusion ,but didn't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write:

```
mult(Ls, Rs, Answer) :-
    findall(X, (member(L, Ls),
                member(R, Rs),
                X is L * R),
            Answer).
```

e.g.

```
?- mult([10,100], [1,2,3], Answer).
Answer = [10, 20, 30, 100, 200, 300]
```

but you are probably supposed to use recursion, so:

```
% Multiply a list of numbers R(ight)s, each by
% one integer L from the original L(eft)s list
mult_row([], _, []).
mult_row([R|Rs], L, [Product|RowAnswers]) :-
    Product is L * R,
    mult_row(Rs, L, RowAnswers).

% Multiply two lists of integers L(eft)s and R(ight)s
mult([], _, []).
mult([L|Ls], Rs, Answers) :-
    mult_row(Rs, L, As1),
    mult(Ls, Rs, As2),
    flatten([As1, As2], Answers).
```

e.g.

```
?- mult([10,100,1000], [1,2,3], Answers).
Answers = [10, 20, 30, 100, 200, 300, 1000, 2000, 3000]
```

To multiply [10,100,1000] * [1,2,3] it does this:

- Take the first number from the left list (10)
- calls mult_row to calculate (10 * 1,2,3)
- that makes a list of [10, 20, 30] into As1.
- Then the remaining [100, 1000] go through this from the start (recursion).
- Take the first number from the left list (100)
- calls mult_row to calculate (100 * 1,2,3)
- that makes a list of [100, 200, 300] into (a new variable) As1.
- Then the remaining [1000] go through this from the start (recursion).
- Take the first number from the left list (1000)
- calls mult_row to calculate (1000 * 1,2,3)
- that makes a list of [1000, 2000, 3000] into (a new variable) As1.
- Then the remaining [] go through this from the start (recursion).
- Take the first number from the left list ([] - empty)
- flatten [[1000, 2000, 3000], []] into Answers [1000, 2000, 3000]
- finish [[100, 200, 300], [1000, 2000, 3000]] into (a new variable) Answers. [100, 200, 300, 1000, 2000, 3000]
- finish [[10, 20, 30], [100, 200, 300], [1000, 2000, 3000]] into (a new variable) answers with the final answer.
- finish.

And the call to mult_row does the same pattern; a recursive walk over the list, multiplying 10x1, 10x2, 10x3 into an answer list, for each row.

Comment: this is for integer number , a good way to give the idea , but for exemple:          multiple([1,1,1,1],[1,1,1],A). the the answer would be a list with 12's 1 , mean all the elements of both lists are the same

Comment: @MohammedAmine I don't understand; What answer do you desire for `[1,1,1,1], [1,1,1]` ?

Comment: i desire   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

Comment: @MohammedAmine ... is that not what my code gives as the answer? `?- mult([1,1,1,1],[1,1,1],A), length(A, Len).` returns  `A = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], Len = 12`.

Comment: @ TessellatingHeckler
yes , sorry i got confused trying to understand recursion ,thanks a lot and sorry for me not quitly getting the grip in prolog.

Comment: @MohammedAmine OK, no problem - it is an unusual language :)

Comment: can you give a simple explenation ? @TessellatingHeckler

Comment: @MohammedAmine I am not sure that I can, without writing a tutorial on Prolog and recursion (which is not simple). I have edited my question with some explanation.